# how to create simple pagination for change folder html + pure JS

Tags: javascript, datatables, pagination, pure-js

how to create change folder pagination?
e.g.:

1. Under folder have some sub-folders, eg: 1, 2, 3,..., future will add A1, A2, A3, A4, ... also will add another name of folders B1, B2, B3, B4, C1, C2, C3 ..., etc.
2. available only choose A's folders',
3. auto detect how many folders for paginate max number.
4. just using HTML + pure JS for create simple pagination.
5. each sub-folder inside have index.html file as default page.
6. each index.html page have one jQuery dataTables (future will change to pure JS)
7. pagination show on each index.html page footer.

i was try co-operating with other pagination, but finally have some bug and cannot solve. such as:

> https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-20
>
> https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/ajax-static-pagination.html
>
> https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/generic-px-pagination/
>
> https://bilalakil.github.io/bin/simplepagination/#page-1

Temporary using px-pagination, it can work for me. But have some side effects still cannot solve, maybe only occur on my case. However, I cannot check it details, that is why, I wish change to pure JS replaced these jQuery, px-pagination, bootstrap, etc.

> https://alumnivtcedu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/nelsonip_alumni_vtc_edu_hk/EbDHrXqbJAFPi3FukvSwm18B0fUbTfHcEC20gSK2ceXjYA?e=qB7F5D

upper hyperlink is my simple finished work, wish listen any comments and suggestions from you! Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: Can you focus on one _specific_ problem that you may be having? Can you show us the relevant code and data for that (in the question, not as links), and explain what the problem is, what you have tried, and what you want to happen instead? You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: my wrote last link is my worked files zipped. Yeah, i wish anyone provide your idea to improve it more simple.